# How to backslash in number using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add backslash in a number dynamically in JavaScript.
I want output like this : '/(123) 456/-7890'

```
let number = '1234567890';

let test = `\(${number.substr(0,3)}) ${number.substr(3,3)}'\'-${number.substr(6,4)}`;
```

Backslash removed after getting the output '(123) 456-7890'

Comment: The slashes in your suggested output are forward-slashes, and a single backslash will be removed from a template string as it's an escape character. You'd need a double backslash (To escape the escape character).

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the `\` because it is a special escape character.

```
let number = '1234567890';

let test = `\\(${number.substr(0,3)}) ${number.substr(3,3)}'\\'-${number.substr(6,4)}`;
```